# How do I change a part of the display when I click a button made on pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game using pygame. It is a some what a tower defense game where on a fixed screen there will be 2 headquarters on opposite ends. The player can deploy towers and train troops. I have 2 buttons - Troops and Towers on the bottom of the screen placed on a panel(basically a rectangle drawn at the bottom of the screen which contains both the buttons). I want to display the available troops when the user clicks on the troops button. I am not able remove the troops and towers button and replace them with the the desired results on the same panel.

This is my button class

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):

        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        # pos[0] = x position of mouse
        # pos[1] = y position of mouse
        # self.x = left part of the button
        # self.x + self.width = right side of the button
        # same principle with the y axis of the button which generates the position and size of the button

        if self.x < pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if self.y < pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
```

This is my main game function

```
def main():
    run = True
    fps = 90
    troops = Button((59, 255, 140), 340, 610, 150, 80, text = "Troops")
    towers = Button((59, 255, 140), 510, 610, 150, 80, text = "Towers")
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pos = (mx, my)
    while run:

        screen.fill((50, 168, 66))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (201, 142, 47), (0, 600, 1000, 100))
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (500,0), (500, 600))
            troops.draw(screen)
            towers.draw(screen)
            over_troops()
            over_towers()
```

This is my function to change the color of the button when the mouse goes over the button "towers". I have a similar function for troops

```
def over_towers():

    towers = Button((59, 255, 140), 510, 610, 150, 80, text = "Towers")
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_pos = (mx, my)
    if towers.isOver(mouse_pos):
        towers = Button((0, 255, 0), 510, 610, 150, 80, text="Towers")
        towers.draw(screen)

    else:
        towers = Button((59, 255, 140), 510, 610, 150, 80, text="Towers")
        towers.draw(screen)
```

I need help to display the available items when the user clicks on the button troops or towers(on the same panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create anew instance of the button class every frame, once is enough. if you make the button class be able to do everything, then it will become easy to do whatever.

You have `over_towers()` to see if the mouse is over and draw the button. Lets move this to the button class.

The button class will need a new parameter for the colour when the mouse is over, lets call is `colour_over`

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, colour_over, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.colour_over
```

Now In the `draw()` method, you can check if the mouse is over and do accordingly

```
def draw(self, win, click, outline=None): #click is true if click happened

        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)


        if self.isOver(pygame.mouse.get()): #if mouse is over the button
            color = self.colour_over
            if click:  #if user click on button
                self.action()     #call button action  will get to this later
        else:
            color = self.color
        pygame.draw.rect(win, color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)



        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))
```

and that should handle the colour change, now for the action of the button. Make a function that does what you want so

```
def Troops_button_pressed():
    #do whatever
```

now you need to create the button with this action

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, colour_over, x, y, width, height, action, text=''):
        self.action = action
```

in `main()`, check for clicks

```
while run:
    click = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #if click
           click = True

   troops.draw(screen, click)
   towers.draw(screen, click)
```

now if the user clicks, the button will call the click function whch you can get to do what you want, so put the troops on the screen

---

To change the buttons to troops, you can make a list of the buttons and draw the them when the troop button gets clicked

```
main_button_list = [troops, towers] #the two main buttons
troops_list = [Button((59, 255, 140), 340, 610, 150, 80, action, text = "Troop 1")...]
#do the same for towers_list
button_state = "main" #this decides what buttons appear on the screen
```

now when drawing

```
if button_state == "main":
    for button in main_button_list:
        button.draw(screen, click)
elif buton_state == "troops":
    for button in troops_list:
        button.draw(screen,click)
...
```

for the action of the buttons, make the main buttons change the `button_state` so

```
def Troops_button_clicked():
    global button_state     #i hate using global, bad practice but have to use here
    button_state = "troops"
```

and for each troop button, you can rather make a function for each troop/tower or make one function and send as a parameter, the button name so it knows what troop it is

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, colour_over, x, y, width, height, text='', send_name = False):
        self.send_name = send_name
```

```
if click:  #if user click on button
    if self.send_name:
         self.action(self.text)
    else:
        self.action()
```

```
def troop_clicked(name):
    #add a troop
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am learning classes and this was actually quite helpful but what I want is for that panel at the bottom to replace the troops and towers buttons with the available troops when the user clicks on troops.

Comment: @rishi Ive update the answer, hopefully its what you're after

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks quite promising. Although I haven'y tried it because I'm planning to display all the items directly on my panel, I'm sure this will work. Thank you for helping me increase my knowledge about classes.